# ng-click event on datalist not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, html-datalist

Iam trying an auto search and on selecting a product., I need to redirect to the product URL associated to selected dropdown. Iam able to get all search results.

I have created datalist for all search list and created `ng-click` event on datalist to send the selected details to controller. But `ng-click` is not working in datalist. Can you help me out

for.eg. in `(key,data)` ., I need to show `data` in front end search box., but on selecting that data from datalist., I need to send its respective `key` to controller

problematic section for your reference (Full code in plunker):

```
<h2>Custom search field</h2>
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  list="suggestions" placeholder="search" ng-model="obj.searchText" ng-focus="searchSuggest()" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" ng-click="showProduct(obj)">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <datalist id="suggestions">
                    <p ng-repeat="values in suggestionResults track by $index"><option ng-repeat="(key,data) in values" value="{{data}}"  ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-click="showProduct({key: key, data: data})"></p>
                </datalist>

            </div>
```

> Here in above code., u can see **key and data**. I need to just show Data value but on selecting one option., i need to send the respective URL link to conroller. Created **datalist in ng-repeat**
>
> **Please select a value from dropdown in textbox from plunker link below**

*

> I have updated plunker so that URL also can be seen in search
>   dropdown., I need to pass that URL to conroller in short. please help
>   me how to achieve it

*

[code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0FAygzd9AqnHg5RVgR8j?p=preview)

Comment: can you just copy problematic code snippet here?

Comment: Added the code of problematic section. You can see the json structure for clarified details. Please select a value from dropdown in textbox

Comment: In your html file check whether the parameter which u r passing to 'showProduct()' is valid or not. Should it be 'obj' or 'obj.searchText'?

Comment: since its a single value, passing it as a obj or single parameter., it is taking the expected value. the selected text is being passed to controller. Now I have to search the json matching that keyword and iterate URL respective to it defined in same json

Answer (score 0):

If your are searching in array of objects, then use **findIndex** Method.

```
   let json_array = [{a:'apple',b:'orange'},{a:'banana',b:'carot'}];
   let position  = json_array.findIndex(key=>key.a == 'banana');
   let its_value = json_array[position].a;
```

Otherwise you need for object value searching, below is an example for that.

```
 function find_by_key(obj,target) {

        let c = -1;
        let find_pos = c;
        loop1:
        for(let i in obj){
            c++;
            loop2:
            for(let g in target){
                if(g == i && target[g] == obj[i]){
                    find_pos = c;
                    break loop1;
                }
            }
        }
        return find_pos;
    }
    let obj = {a:'Apple',b:'Orange'};

    let find = find_by_key(obj,{a:'Apple'});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your ng-click="showProduct(obj)" and add it to

```
<p ng-repeat="values in suggestionResults track by $index">
    <option ng-repeat="(key,data) in values" value="{{data}}" ng-click="showProduct({key: key, data: data})">
    {{key}}
</p>
```

in showProduct

```
$scope.showProduct = function(data){
    console.log(data.key, data.data);
}
```

data.key is your redirect url

Comment: ng-click is not getting triggered from <datalist> options

Comment: for test remove datalist and use <ul> list

Comment: It is working with ul li. But the requirement is to make it work on click 'search icon'. Atleast on data-list click. Coz it requires auto search filter.

Comment: ok, then you can try to add model to <datalist id="suggestions" ng-model="userSelection"> and on search button pass userSelection to showProduct method

Comment: Thats fine. But how can I pass URL in ng-model="userSelection".. coz ng-model takes what is stored in value="" 'attribute'., since we are storing only 'text' but not URL., again it passes same text. Please let me know if iam wrong. I will try again